# Deleting a row using LINQ query - model mapped is not a column in table - MySqlException: Unknown column

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm trying to delete a record from table "blog" with blogId, but I'm receiving the below error when clicking the delete button in the view
**MySqlException: Unknown column 'b.lastName' in 'field list'**
From my understanding its trying to use the viewmodel which contains lastName property. This property is not mapped [NotMapped] so I'm not sure why the delete LINQ query is doing this.

The blog db table only consists of...
| blogID | blogContent | userID | publishedDate | blogTitle

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Delete(int Id)
        {

            var deleteBlogID = (from b in _db.blog
                                where b.blogID == Id
                                select b).FirstOrDefault();
            
            if (deleteBlogID != null)
            {

                _db.blog.Remove(deleteBlogID);

            }

 
            return RedirectToAction("Display");
        }
```

Model

```
public class BlogViewModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int blogID { get; set; }

        public string blogTitle { get; set; }
        public string blogContent { get; set; }
        public string userID { get; set; }
        public DateTime publishedDate { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        //Wrap CommentModel in this model, so we can use two models in razor view
        public IEnumerable<CommentModel> Comments { get; set; }

    }
```

View

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.ViewModels.BlogViewModel>


section...
               <tbody id="sortable" style="cursor:pointer;">
                    @foreach (var v in Model)
                    {
                        <tr onclick="location.href = '@(Url.Action("Display", "Blog", new { @bp = v.blogID }))'">
                            <td>@v.blogID</td>
                            <td>@v.blogTitle</td>
                            <td>@v.publishedDate</td>
                            <td>@(v.firstName + " " + v.lastName)</td>
                            <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Blog", new { @Id = v.blogID })</td>
                            <td>@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Blog", new { @Id = v.blogID })</td>
                            @*<td><partial name="_DisplayEmployeePartial" model="v"></td>*@

                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
```

DbContext

```
        public DbSet<Employee> employee { get; set; }
        public DbSet<BlogViewModel> blog { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to fix your BlogViewModel. You have not mapped only  a firstName property. You will have to add [NotMapped] to a lastName too

```
 [NotMapped]
 public string firstName { get; set; }
 [NotMapped]
 public string lastName { get; set; }
```